# How can I print the contents of an array horizontally?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Why doesn't the console window print the array contents horizontally rather than vertically?

Is there a way to change that?

How can I display the content of my array horizontally instead of vertically, with a `Console.WriteLine()`?

For example:

```
int[] numbers = new int[100]
for(int i; i < 100; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = i;
}

for (int i; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this one as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033938/system-int32-displaying-instead-of-array-elements/18041923#18041923

Answer (score 137):

You are probably using `Console.WriteLine` for printing the array.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach(var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

If you don't want to have every item on a separate line use `Console.Write`:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach(var item in array)
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
}
```

or `string.Join<T>` (in .NET Framework 4 or later):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));
```

Comment: The last example only works for arrays of strings, doesn't it?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: The last example calls [`String.Join<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This method has been introduced in .NET Framework 4 only.

Comment: Ah, OK. I tried it out on Ideone, but they use a version of Mono that doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: in response to Nicola. any object that implements or overrides ToString() can output it's contents for debugging purposes as it sees fit. handy feature.

Answer (score 32):

I would suggest:

```
foreach(var item in array)
  Console.Write("{0}", item);
```

As written above, except it does not raise an exception if one item is `null`.

```
Console.Write(string.Join(" ", array));
```

would be perfect if the array is a `string[]`.

Answer (score 19):

Just loop through the array and write the items to the console using `Write` instead of `WriteLine`:

```
foreach(var item in array)
    Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
```

As long as your items don't have any line breaks, that will produce a single line.

...or, as Jon Skeet said, provide a little more context to your question.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to pretty print an array of arrays, something like this could work: *[Pretty Print Array of Arrays in .NET C#](http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/11/pretty-print-array-of-arrays-in-net-c.html)*

```
public string PrettyPrintArrayOfArrays(int[][] arrayOfArrays)
{
  if (arrayOfArrays == null)
    return "";

  var prettyArrays = new string[arrayOfArrays.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.Length; i++)
  {
    prettyArrays[i] = "[" + String.Join(",", arrayOfArrays[i]) + "]";
  }

  return "[" + String.Join(",", prettyArrays) + "]";
}
```

Example Output:

```
[[2,3]]

[[2,3],[5,4,3]]

[[2,3],[5,4,3],[8,9]]
```

Answer (score 5):

The below solution is the simplest one:

```
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", array));
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Another short solution:

```
Array.ForEach(array,  val => Console.Write("{0} ", val));
```

Output: `1 2 3 4 5`. Or if you need to add add `,`, use the below:

```
int i = 0;
Array.ForEach(array,  val => Console.Write(i == array.Length -1) ? "{0}" : "{0}, ", val));
```

Output: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var item in array)
Console.Write(item.ToString() + "\t");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace ReverseString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stat = "This is an example of code" +
                          "This code has written in C#\n\n";

            Console.Write(stat);

            char[] myArrayofChar = stat.ToCharArray();

            Array.Reverse(myArrayofChar);

            foreach (char myNewChar in myArrayofChar)
                Console.Write(myNewChar); // You just need to write the function
                                          // Write instead of WriteLine
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the output:

```
#C ni nettirw sah edoc sihTedoc fo elpmaxe na si sihT
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] n=new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    n[i] = i + 100;
}

foreach (int j in n)
{
    int i = j - 100;

    Console.WriteLine("Element [{0}]={1}", i, j);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[10];

    Console.Write("index ");

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
        Console.Write(numbers[i] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("value ");

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbers.Length - i;
        Console.Write(numbers[i] + " ");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Maybe tell the OP what he did wrong and how you fixed it?

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Using Console.Write only works if the thread is the only thread writing to the Console, otherwise your output may be interspersed with other output that may or may not insert newlines, as well as other undesired characters.  To ensure your array is printed intact, use Console.WriteLine to write one string.  Most any array of objects can be printed horizontally (depending on the type's ToString() method) using the non-generic Join available before .NET 4.0:

```
        int[] numbers = new int[100];
        for(int i= 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = i;
        }

        //For clarity
        IEnumerable strings = numbers.Select<int, string>(j=>j.ToString());
        string[] stringArray = strings.ToArray<string>();
        string output = string.Join(", ", stringArray);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        //OR 

        //For brevity
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers.Select<int, string>(j => j.ToString()).ToArray<string>()));
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question at hand. OP never even mentioned threads.

Comment: This answer has everything to do with the question at hand.  It is a one-line, .NET 3.5 compatible solution to the problem using LINQ and the non-generic string.Join method, that also guards against interrupted output from other threads.  If you felt my wording of that makes the answer appear heavy on the multi-threading issue, then editing would be far more helpful than declaring a unique and valid solution as irrelevant and down voting it. Down vote if you feel you must, but did you down vote the answers using Console.Write when the OP explicitly asked "...with a Console.WriteLine()?"

Answer (score 0):

I have written some extensions to accommodate almost any need.
There are extension overloads to feed with **Separator**, **String.Format** and **IFormatProvider**.

**Example:**

```
var array1 = new byte[] { 50, 51, 52, 53 };
var array2 = new double[] { 1.1111, 2.2222, 3.3333 };
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ja-JP");

Console.WriteLine("Byte Array");
//Normal print 
Console.WriteLine(array1.StringJoin());
//Format to hex values
Console.WriteLine(array1.StringJoin("-", "0x{0:X2}"));
//Comma separated 
Console.WriteLine(array1.StringJoin(", "));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Double Array");
//Normal print 
Console.WriteLine(array2.StringJoin());
//Format to Japanese culture
Console.WriteLine(array2.StringJoin(culture));
//Format to three decimals 
Console.WriteLine(array2.StringJoin(" ", "{0:F3}"));
//Format to Japanese culture and two decimals
Console.WriteLine(array2.StringJoin(" ", "{0:F2}", culture));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Extensions:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IEnumerable Utilities. 
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class IEnumerableUtilities
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// String.Join collection of items using custom Separator, String.Format and FormatProvider. 
        /// </summary>
        public static string StringJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source)
        {
            return Source.StringJoin(" ", string.Empty, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// String.Join collection of items using custom Separator, String.Format and FormatProvider. 
        /// </summary>
        public static string StrinJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source, string Separator)
        {
            return Source.StringJoin(Separator, string.Empty, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// String.Join collection of items using custom Separator, String.Format and FormatProvider. 
        /// </summary>
        public static string StringJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source, string Separator, string StringFormat)
        {
            return Source.StringJoin(Separator, StringFormat, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// String.Join collection of items using custom Separator, String.Format and FormatProvider. 
        /// </summary>
        public static string StringJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source, string Separator, IFormatProvider FormatProvider)
        {
            return Source.StringJoin(Separator, string.Empty, FormatProvider);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// String.Join collection of items using custom Separator, String.Format and FormatProvider. 
        /// </summary>
        public static string StringJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source, IFormatProvider FormatProvider)
        {
            return Source.StringJoin(" ", string.Empty, FormatProvider);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// String.Join collection of items using custom Separator, String.Format and FormatProvider. 
        /// </summary>
        public static string StringJoin<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source, string Separator, string StringFormat, IFormatProvider FormatProvider)
        {
            //Validate Source
            if (Source == null)
                return string.Empty;
            else if (Source.Count() == 0)
                return string.Empty;

            //Validate Separator
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Separator))
                Separator = " ";

            //Validate StringFormat
            if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(StringFormat))
                StringFormat = "{0}";

            //Validate FormatProvider 
            if (FormatProvider == null)
                FormatProvider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

            //Convert items 
            var convertedItems = Source.Select(i => String.Format(FormatProvider, StringFormat, i));

            //Return 
            return String.Join(Separator, convertedItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private int[,] MirrorH(int[,] matrix)               //the method will return mirror horizintal of matrix
{
    int[,] MirrorHorizintal = new int[4, 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
        {
            MirrorHorizintal[i, j] = matrix[i, 3 - j];
        }
    }
    return MirrorHorizintal;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.