# System.Int32[] displaying instead of Array elements

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to display array elements but always getting this output `System.Int32[]`
instead of integer elements.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr=new int [26];
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

        Console.WriteLine("Array line : "+arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# - printing contents of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700448/c-sharp-printing-contents-of-array) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856/how-to-join-int-to-a-character-separated-string-in-net

Comment: If you still have any ambiguity have a look at my suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

You could use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
 Console.WriteLine("Array line : "+ string.Join(",", arr));
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to loop over the content and print them -

```
Console.WriteLine("Array line: ");
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
     arr[i]=i;
     Console.WriteLine(" " + arr[i]);
}
```

Simply printing `arr` will call `ToString()` on array and `print its type`.

Answer (score 2):

Printing an array will call the `ToString()` method of an array and it will print the name of the class which is a default behaviour. To overcome this issue we normally overrides `ToString` function of the class.

As per the discussion here [we can not override Array.ToString()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82a3662d-6546-44c4-94df-59bd1fc592d1/override-arraytostring) instead `List` can be helpful.

Simple and direct solutions have already been suggested but I would like to make your life even more easier by embedding the functionality in [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) (framework 3.5 or above) :

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static string ArrayToString(this Array arr)
    {
        List<object> lst = new List<object>();
        object[] obj = new object[arr.Length];
        Array.Copy(arr, obj, arr.Length);

        lst.AddRange(obj);
        return string.Join(",", lst.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Add the above code in your namespace and use it like this: (sample code)

```
float[] arr = new float[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    arr[i] = Convert.ToSingle(i + 0.5);

string str = arr.ArrayToString();
Debug.Print(str);  // See output window
```

Hope you will find it very helpful.

NOTE: It should work for all the data types because of type `object`. I have tested on few of them

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this problem because your line

```
Console.WriteLine("Array line : "+arr);
```

is actually printing the `type of arr`. If you want to print element values you should use the index number to print the value like

```
Console.WriteLine("Array line : "+arr[0]);
```