# Array returns System.Int32[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, return

When I make a function to return an array with the correct results.
Instead of giving me the correct results, I get as result System.Int32[].
Anyone an idea why this is?

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MultiplyByLength(new int[] {2,3,1,0}));
    }

    public static int[] MultiplyByLength(int[] arr)
    {
        return arr.Select(x => x * arr.Length).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Int32\[\] displaying instead of Array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033938/system-int32-displaying-instead-of-array-elements)

Comment: What result do you **want**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format it some how. An array doesn't have a `ToString()` *override* that knows how you want to format your type (`int[]`) to a `string`, in such cases it just returns the *type name* (which is what you are seeing)

```
foreach(var item in MultiplyByLength(new int[] {2,3,1,0})
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MultiplyByLength(new int[] {2,3,1,0}));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", MultiplyByLength(new int[] {2,3,1,0}));
```