# array keeps on outputting "System.Int32[ ]" whenever I try to output an array - anyone know why?

Tags: vb.net

```
For numberOfRunsCompleted As Integer = 0 To arrayToSort.Length
    For valueWithinArray As Integer = 0 To arrayToSort.Length - 2
        If arrayToSort(arrayValue) > arrayToSort(arrayValue + 1) Then
            Dim tempStorage As Integer = arrayToSort(arrayValue)
            arrayToSort(arrayValue) = arrayToSort(arrayValue + 1)
            arrayToSort(arrayValue + 1) = tempStorage
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The array is declared as `arrayToSort(7)`, being the integers from 9 to 2 inclusive.

Comment: sorry guys I'm new to visual basic and visual studio rn :)

Comment: What is `arrayValue` and where doesn't come from? Where exactly in your code are you "outputting the array"? If I had to guess, somewhere in your code (the part that you didn't show us), your using something like `Console.WriteLine(arrayToSort)` instead of `Console.WriteLine(arrayToSort(someValue))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Int32\[\] displaying instead of Array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033938/system-int32-displaying-instead-of-array-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of your variable `valueWithinArray` to `index`. It really isn't the value in the array, it is the index of the element. You introduced another undeclared variable (`arrayValue`) where you really wanted `valueWithinArray` (now called `index`).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim arrayToSort() As Integer = {6, 8, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5, 3}
    For numberOfRunsCompleted As Integer = 0 To arrayToSort.Length
        For index As Integer = 0 To arrayToSort.Length - 2
            If arrayToSort(index) > arrayToSort(index + 1) Then
                Dim tempStorage As Integer = arrayToSort(index)
                arrayToSort(index) = arrayToSort(index + 1)
                arrayToSort(index + 1) = tempStorage
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each i In arrayToSort
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

That was a good learning excercise but to save some typing...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim arrayToSort() As Integer = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}
    Array.Sort(arrayToSort)
    For Each i In arrayToSort
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

The results will show up in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have only been using visual basic for 6 weeks or so so I need to learn half of this XD but I will check on microsoft docs what some of this does. Thanks!