# PHP var_dump in C# to dump array or objects?

Tags: c#

I need to dump the content of arrays or objects and I am interested to know if in C# we have something like PHP instruction `var_dump`.

The objective is to not build a loop to use every property or content of array or object and print with `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: You don't want to use the built-in inspection tools in visual studio? like quickwatch?

Comment: You could serialize it to JSON string with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVar)`

Comment: In Visual Studio, use the [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2022) and type e.g. `?User.Claims` to print the result. Do not confuse `?` with the ternary operator - this is a *command* supported by the Immediate Window, which will print things like `IEnumerable<string>` in full detail.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The closest thing would probably be `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myEnumOfObjects));
```

It would not automatically include "every property or content of array or object" into the output, though - if you want that to happen, you need to override the `ToString` method of the object being printed:

```
class MyObject {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime Dob {get;set;}
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Name, Dob);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you insert a break point you can easily view the contents of an array by hovering your mouse over it.

or any of these:

You are probably using Console.WriteLine for printing the array.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach(var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

If you don't want to have every item on a separate line use Console.Write:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach(var item in array)
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
}
```

or string.Join (in .NET Framework 4 or later):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));
```

from this question: [How to print contents of array horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700448/how-to-print-contents-of-array-horizontally)

Comment: the idea is not to use loops just one instruction and print it in console directly

Comment: @David Look at the last one.

Comment: I didnt see it true, my idea i need to see Keys and values inserted inside SESSION

Comment: @David I think you should just use a forloop. Why don't you want to?

Comment: because I want it as a simple line like var_dump , Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));, is good for me

Answer (score 3):

I think there aren't direct equivalent of var_dump php function.

You must use reflection to write an equivalent function.

If you search in web, you can easily find code which do it.

For example : http://ruuddottech.blogspot.fr/2009/07/php-vardump-method-for-c.html

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to avoid loop, but if its just for the sake of writing multiple lines of code, below is a one liner loop that could allow you to print data with single line for Objects extend ForEach Method

```
List<string> strings=new List<string>{"a","b","c"};//declare one

strings.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));//single line loop...for printing and is easier to write
```

Comment: var_dump can print any value of one object ... classes, integers, any .... simply with vardump(object_variable), the idea is not to make a loop